# Sum based on two flags

Tags: r

I need your help. I have a data with one numeric field and two flags. 
I want to sum the numeric filed based on two flags .
In the below data :
I want to calculate sum between FLAG1 and FLAG2.  But when the FLAG2 is TRUE then the next FLAG1 row value should be made TRUE and before any FLAG2 is true , FLAG one should be considered as False.

```
nf<-c(10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,110,120,130,140,150,160,180,190,200,210,220,230,240,250)
Flag1 <- c('FALSE','FALSE','FALSE','FALSE','FALSE','TRUE','FALSE','FALSE','FALSE','FALSE','FALSE','TRUE','FALSE','FALSE','FALSE','FALSE','FALSE','FALSE','FALSE','TRUE','FALSE','FALSE','FALSE','FALSE','FALSE')
Flag2 <- c('FALSE','FALSE','FALSE','FALSE','FALSE','FALSE','FALSE','FALSE','TRUE','FALSE','FALSE','FALSE','FALSE','FALSE','FALSE','TRUE','FALSE','FALSE','FALSE','FALSE','FALSE','FALSE','FALSE','FALSE','TRUE')


abc <- as.data.frame(cbind(Flag1,Flag2,nf))
```

Output I am looking for is  :
numeric field sum of 300,910 and 1890.

60+70+80+90 =300 100+110+120+130+140+150+160 After the second flag value is TRUE, firstflag next row value should become true and any subsequent value which is true in flag 1 should turn to false.

please guide.

Regards, Rohit

Comment: logical  vectors don't need quotes

Comment: Also, `170` missing from `nf` - and please describe how you arrive at expected sums of 300, 910, 1890.

Comment: 60+70+80+90 =300
100+110+120+130+140+150+160 After the second flag value is TRUE, firstflag next row value should become true and any subsequent value which is true in flag 1 should turn to false.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is what you need, but thought it might be helpful.

First, as mentioned by @akrun, `TRUE` and `FALSE` are logical vectors and don't need to be put in quotes as strings. I converted them to logical values for this example.

This solution uses `tidyverse`. You can flip your `Flag1` values in preceding or subsequent rows as you described using `lead` and `lag`. Using `slice` you can start your sums beginning with the first `TRUE` in `Flag1`. Using `cumsum` you can number your groups that always end with `Flag2` being `TRUE`.

```
nf<-c(10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,110,120,130,140,150,160,170,180,190,200,210,220,230,240,250)

Flag1 <- c('FALSE','FALSE','FALSE','FALSE','FALSE','TRUE','FALSE','FALSE','FALSE','FALSE','FALSE','TRUE',
           'FALSE','FALSE','FALSE','FALSE','FALSE','FALSE','FALSE','TRUE','FALSE','FALSE','FALSE','FALSE','FALSE')
Flag2 <- c('FALSE','FALSE','FALSE','FALSE','FALSE','FALSE','FALSE','FALSE','TRUE','FALSE','FALSE','FALSE',
           'FALSE','FALSE','FALSE','TRUE','FALSE','FALSE','FALSE','FALSE','FALSE','FALSE','FALSE','FALSE','TRUE')

Flag1 <- Flag1 == 'TRUE'
Flag2 <- Flag2 == 'TRUE'

abc <- data.frame(Flag1,Flag2,nf)

library(tidyverse)

abc %>%
  mutate(Flag1 = if_else(lag(Flag2), TRUE, Flag1),
         Flag1 = if_else(lead(Flag2), FALSE, Flag1)) %>%
  slice(match(TRUE, Flag1):n()) %>%
  group_by(grp = cumsum(lag(Flag2, default = 0))) %>%
  summarise(sum = sum(nf))

# A tibble: 3 x 2
    grp   sum
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     0   300
2     1   910
3     2  1890
```